# Using Custom Entities with OpenIddict

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, openiddict

I'm trying to extend the entities used by OpenIddict based on the example provided here:
https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/360#issuecomment-280268525

This includes creating entity classes extending those given by OpenIddict:

```
public class CustomApplication : OpenIddictApplication<Guid, CustomAuthorization, CustomToken>
{
    public string ImpersonateUser { get; set; }
}

public class CustomAuthorization : OpenIddictAuthorization<Guid, CustomApplication, CustomToken>
{

}

public class CustomScope : OpenIddictScope<Guid>
{

}

public class CustomToken : OpenIddictToken<Guid, CustomApplication, CustomAuthorization>
{

}
```

Updating `AddDbContext`:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"));
    options.UseOpenIddict<CustomApplication, CustomAuthorization, CustomScope, CustomToken, Guid>();
});
```

And a modified version of the call to register the services, to match the newer API:

```
services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(options =>
    {

        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore().UseDbContext<ApplicationContext>()
            .ReplaceDefaultEntities<CustomApplication, CustomAuthorization, CustomScope, CustomToken, Guid>();
    })
```

Everything appears fine up to this point. Then, as part of application startup, I check for an existing client, and create it if it's not found:

```
var manager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<OpenIddictApplicationManager<CustomApplication>>();

if (await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("Application") == null) // Throws Here
{
    var descriptor = new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
    {
        ClientId = "Application",
        ClientSecret = "application-default-secret",
        DisplayName = "Application",
        RedirectUris = { new Uri("http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc")},
        Permissions = { OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
            OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Logout,
            OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
            OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
            OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.RefreshToken,
            OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Email,
            OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Profile,
            OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Roles}
    };
    await manager.CreateAsync(descriptor);
}
```

As noted by the "Throws Here" comment, an exception is thrown which is a SqlException:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (9ms) [Parameters=[@__identifier='Application' (Size = 100)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(1) [application].[Id], [application].[ClientId], [application].[ClientSecret], [application].[ConcurrencyToken], [application].[ConsentType], [application].[DisplayName], [application].[ImpersonateUser], [application].[Permissions], [application].[PostLogoutRedirectUris], [application].[Properties], [application].[RedirectUris], [application].[Type]
      FROM [OpenIddictApplications] AS [application]
      WHERE [application].[ClientId] = @__identifier
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'ImpersonateUser'.
```

It appears somewhere along the way, it's trying to query the old tables instead of the newer ones that I'm specifying. The only things on the callstack for OpenIddict between my seed method, and the SQL exception are `` OpenIddict.Core.OpenIddictApplicationManager`1.FindByClientIdAsync(String identifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken) `` and `` OpenIddict.Core.OpenIddictApplicationCache`1.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<<FindByClientIdAsync>g__ExecuteAsync|0>d.MoveNext() ``

Comment: DId you generate a migration after adding the `ImpersonateUser` column to your EF Entity? I guess the tutorial does not specify this since people might not use it together with a database. But in that case, you have to update it, in order to be able to query it.

Comment: @jpgrassi The new entities should be pointed to different tables, `CustomApplications` instead of `OpenIddictApplications`. Those tables exist, with the expected columns. The issue comes from something is trying to make queries against the `CustomApplication` entity and it's going to the `OpenIddictApplications` table

Comment: @MattSieker do you override the table names using `ToTable` from `OnModelConfiguring`? If you don't, your custom tables won't be used, as OpenIddict uses `ToTable` internally.

Comment: @Pinpoint that worked, I was missing that bit. You want to make that an answer and I'll accept it?